# When and why should i use portlets

Tags: java, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

Currently i was reading about portlets and Spring MVC portlets.

I still can't see the benefit of using portlets, what are the advantages, what are the situations that portlets will be a perfect solution for them.

I googled a little but couldn't come with a concrete answer. I know  this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983282/please-discuss-what-are-and-why-use-portlets)  but it is a bit old and not well-explained. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Consider e.g. these features defined by portal specs (just a very few):

- Portlet lifecycle, isolated from other portlets.
- Isolated URL spaces for each portlet
- Portlet modes and window states
- Portlet session scopes Personalization, portlet preferences.
- Users configure appearance of their portal pages by positioning and setting individual portlets.
- Raising / consuming of events (JSR-286)
- From the point of view of the job of just 'including' some dynamic/static content on a web page.

However there are a number of conveniences implemented, such as support for personalisation of the portlet (at the portlet/'include' level) and storing this info, a more rigid workflow for configuring what is displayed in the portlet and so on.

Plus obviously there's all the portlet arrangement code that you would have to write otherwise. Some portlet servers do a lot on the client side for arrangement (drag and drop of portlets etc).